# Prevent child element css from over writing

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have two divs. Inner div (positioned absolute) is placed under outer Div (positioned relative).
I have applied jquery toggle events on outer div  to show and hide the inner div. I also want to change the opacity of outer div when click is done , then on second click outer div opacity should again be set to normal.

But issue is along with outer div , inner div's opacity is also getting set , even though I applied important flag in css also made child class more specific  .

css of child class here :

```
> div#child.childclass {
      position:absolute;
      display:none;
      width:100px;
      left:15px;
      top:-20px;
      background-color:red;
      font-size:12px;
      text-align:center;
      opacity:1 !important;
  }
```

Fiddle example here : [fiddle for above issue](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/Lk8h0xxg/5/)

Thanks

Comment: Since you apply opacity to the parent element you can't set the opacity in child element back to default it will inherit the opacity from the parent element.

Comment: Use rgba background colors instead of opacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opacity value of an element affects its content and therefore all its children elements.

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

Source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

**Workaround :**

In your case, you can use `rgba()` color for the green dot and border. `rgba()` is a color value with opacity. This will change the opacity of the colors : green dot and border color without affecting the child element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Lk8h0xxg/9/)**

```js
;
var $p = $("div#parent");
var $c = $("div#child");

function firstFn(e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget) { //not correct div
        console.log(e.target);
        return;
    }
    console.log("first click");
    $c.css("display", 'block');
    $p.addClass("active");

}

function secondFn(e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget) { //not correct div
        console.log(e.target);
        return;
    }
    console.log("second click");
    $c.css("display", 'none');
    $p.removeClass("active");


}


// adding toggle function
$p.toggle(

function (e) {
    firstFn(e);
},

function (e) {
    secondFn(e);
});
```

```css
  div#parent {
      width:20px;
      background-color:green;
      height:20px;
      margin:50px;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:relative;
      border:1px solid black;
      border-radius:100%;
  }
  div#child.childclass {
      position:absolute;
      display:none;
      width:100px;
      left:15px;
      top:-20px;
      background-color:red;
      font-size:12px;
      text-align:center;
      opacity:1 !important;
  }
  div#parent.active {
      background-color:rgba(0, 128, 0, .5);
      border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
toggle clicks on green circle
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child" class="childclass">some text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , It solved the issue . but I didnt get why opacity overrides children but rgba() not ? eventhough I make child more specific and use !important

Comment: @Bhupendra check the updated answer, I hope you understand better.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container { position: relative; }  

div#parent {
      width:20px;
      background-color:green;
      height:20px;
      margin:50px;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:relative;
      border:1px solid black;
      border-radius:100%;
  }
  div#child.childclass {
      position:absolute;
      width:100px;
      left:15px;
      top:-20px;
      background-color:red;
      font-size:12px;
      text-align:center;
      opacity:1 !important;
  }
  .active {
      opacity:.5
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child" class="childclass">some text here</div>
    <div id="parent" class="active"></div>
</div>
```

Simply put, a child element **cannot** have a greater opacity than it's parent element.

Once you set the opacity of an element, then it, and all of it's children (and all of it's children's children, etc) will inherit that opacity.

Even if you do:

```
#parent { opacity:0.5; }
#child { opacity: 0.7; }
```

`#child` will actually have an opacity of 0.35 (which is 70% of an opacity of 0.5 - the opacity of it's parent).

The only solution is to have the `#child` in your example, not be a `descendent` of `#parent`, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8h0xxg/6/

Comment: Hi adam ,thanks for answer , but I want to place child element relative to parent only . why  !Important is not able prevent inner div from being overriden..

Comment: Then you need to add another container element - modify your HTML. The bottom line is, a child cannot have a higher opacity than it's parent. If you're having trouble positioning HTML elements, feel free to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

separate both the parent and child and position it as per the `#container`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lk8h0xxg/7/

```js
var $p = $("div#parent");
var $c = $("div#child");

function firstFn(e) {
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) { //not correct div
    console.log(e.target);
    return;
  }
  console.log("first click");
  $c.css("display", 'block');
  $p.addClass("active");

}

function secondFn(e) {
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) { //not correct div
    console.log(e.target);
    return;
  }
  console.log("second click");
  $c.css("display", 'none');
  $p.removeClass("active");


}


// adding toggle function
$p.toggle(

  function(e) {
    firstFn(e);
  },

  function(e) {
    secondFn(e);
  });
```

```css
div#container {
  position: relative;
}
div#parent {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
div#child.childclass {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  left: 46px;
  top: -20px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.active {
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
toggle clicks on green circle
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <div id="child" class="childclass">some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Vitorino for answer , I cant separate child element from parent as child element will have notification no so  , I need to place inner chid(absolute) to parent (relative)

Comment: you can use `#container` for giving `position:relative` like in my example